# Postfix not sending mail :

Tags: postfix, smtp, gmail

I have postfix installed on my webserver and, since a couple of days, it seems that it cannot send mail anymore.

All my messages are in postfix queue and I have each time the following message (extract from mail.log):

```
May 14 13:01:35 *** postfix/smtp[31011]: connect to mx01.emig.gmx.net[213.165.67.97]:25: Connection timed out
May 14 13:02:05 *** postfix/smtp[31011]: connect to mx00.emig.gmx.net[213.165.67.99]:25: Connection timed out
```

(here it was a message with gmx account destination)
But for message where the receiver is a gmail adress it's exactly the same:

```
May 14 13:03:43 *** postfix/smtp[31011]: connect to aspmx.l.google.com[173.194.66.26]:25: Connection timed out
May 14 13:04:13 *** postfix/smtp[31011]: connect to alt2.aspmx.l.google.com[74.125.25.26]:25: Connection timed out
May 14 13:04:43 *** postfix/smtp[31011]: connect to alt1.aspmx.l.google.com[74.125.143.26]:25: Connection timed out
```

weird no ? I run a black list test but my webserver does not seem to be listed on thoses black list services.

Anyone can help me on this ?

Thanks you very much in advance and I wish you all a nice day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps your ISP or server provider has closed outbound port 25 in their firewall? Contact your server provider and ask them what's going on.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer.
I have a root access on my server do you know how can I check this with  a shell acess on my server to see if outbound on port 25 has been closed ?
I don't think my server provider would do that it's a giant company (OVH) and I would have been notified if it was the case.

Comment: you were completely right. OVH Blocked as you said automatically outbound port 25 on their firewall because of a infected wordpress sending too much mail. Suceeded to switch off this anti-spam protection on the webadmin of ovh customer account. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Janne Pikkarainen was completely right. 
OVH Blocked automatically outbound port 25 on their firewall because of a infected wordpress sending too much mail. 
I Suceeded to switch off this anti-spam protection on the webadmin of ovh customer account. Thanks again.

It was not easy to find out as OVH never sent me a mail concerning this issue.